# Numba/jit with list of functions as function argument

Tags: python, jit, numba, ode

I am trying to speed up an ODE-solution by jitting the function and its time-dependent parameters (rate functions). I have jitted the rate functions successfully and am now having trouble handling the list of rate functions:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def makerates(): #generates a list of 3 jitted rate functions
    b_f = 1

    def rateBackward(n,b_f):
        
        @njit
        def  rate(t):
            return b_f*n*t
        return rate
    
    return [rateBackward(i,b_f) for i in range(3)]

rates=makerates() #gives the list  [r1(t), r2(t), r3(t)]

@njit
def dy2(t,y,*argv):

    ####this works:
    r1=argv[0](t)
    r2=argv[1](t)
    r3 = argv[2](t)
    print(r1,r2,r3)
    
    ####this doesn't:
    # for i in range(3):
    #     print(argv[i](t))
            
    return y

y0 = 1
t_span=[0,1]
sol2 = solve_ivp(dy2, t_span, [y0],args=(*rates,))
```

Numba doesn't like heterogeneous lists, so I'm passing the rate functions by unpacking the list which seems to work fine. I would however like some way to iterate over the argv in dy2, but I cannot figure out how to do that. If I uncomment the part in dy2,  it throws the error

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (Tuple(type(CPUDispatcher(<function makerates.<locals>.rateBackward.<locals>.rate at 0x0000022C74F040D0>)), type(CPUDispatcher(<function makerates.<locals>.rateBackward.<locals>.rate at 0x0000022C74F04D08>)), type(CPUDispatcher(<function makerates.<locals>.rateBackward.<locals>.rate at 0x0000022C74F04840>))), int64)
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 10:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 11:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 12:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 13:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 14:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 15:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
```

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

import timeit

def makerates(): #generates a list of 3 jitted rate functions
    b_f = 1
    

    def rateBackward(n,b_f):
        
        @njit
        def  rate(t):
            return b_f*n*t
        return rate
    
    return [rateBackward(i,b_f) for i in range(3)]

rates=makerates() #gives the list  [r1(t), r2(t), r3(t)]



@njit
def dy2(t,y,*argv):

    ####this works:
    r1=argv[0](t)
    r2=argv[1](t)
    r3 = argv[2](t)
    #print(r1,r2,r3)
    
    ####this doesn't:
    # for i in range(3):
    #     print(argv[i](t))
            
    return y

@njit
def dy2_n(t,y,*n):
    b_f=1
    #r1,r2,r3 = [(lambda x:b_f*ni*x)(t) for ni in n]
    
    r1= b_f*n[0]*t
    r2= b_f*n[1]*t
    r3= b_f*n[2]*t
    #print(r1,r2,r3)

    return y



n_test = [i for i in range(3)]
def time_func():
    #solve_ivp(dy2, t_span, [y0],args=(*rates,))
    solve_ivp(dy2_n, t_span, [y0],args=(*n_test,))

y0 = 1
t_span=[0,1]

n_time=1000
print(timeit.Timer(time_func).timeit(number=n_time)) # 6.637224912643433 seconds
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the functions as parameters? Or can you just define the functions somewhere in your code and call them in the ODE right-hand-side.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but in general, I do not think it is a good idea to iterate over different function calls because it is slow. Every-time a different function is called, there is overhead. This is why people inline functions ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)). 

One call of `dy2` takes 280 microseconds. I re-wrote your code so that the value of `n` is passed into `dy2`, instead of different functions. One call of this new function takes 300 nanoseconds - nearly 1000x faster!

Comment: Thanks very much for both of your suggestions! I'm not sure I can implement your suggestions into the project that caused me to ask this question but I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but could you explain what exactly you did? I get only about 10x increase in speed, even if I write out the r_i  explicitly (I included the changed code in the edit above)...

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from comments...

> Sorry if this is obvious, but could you explain what exactly you did? I get only about 10x increase in speed, even if I write out the r_i explicitly

Your implementation is fine, but we were measuring the time of different operations. I was measuring the time it took to do one call to `dy2`. You are measuring the time it takes to do one integration with solve_ivp. solve_ivp has [massive overhead](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8257) for small integrations like this, so the speedup achieved by passing parameters (`n`) instead of functions is diluted to 10x instead of 1000x.

Here is the speed of 3 different approaches

|  | Time to call `dy` once | Time to do integration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Passing functions + solve_ivp | 275 μs | 4457 μs |
| Passing parameters (n) + solve_ivp | 0.053 μs | 627 μs |
| Passing parameters (n) + NumbaLSODA | 0.053 μs | 5.29 μs |

Here is an implementation of each

### Passing functions + solve_ivp (your original code)

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import timeit

def makerates(): #generates a list of 3 jitted rate functions
    b_f = 1
    def rateBackward(n,b_f):
        @nb.njit
        def  rate(t):
            return b_f*n*t
        return rate
    return [rateBackward(i,b_f) for i in range(3)]

rates=makerates() #gives the list  [r1(t), r2(t), r3(t)]

@nb.njit
def dy2(t,y,*argv):
    r1=argv[0](t)
    r2=argv[1](t)
    r3 = argv[2](t)       
    return y

def time_dy2():
    dy2(1.0,1.0,*rates)

n_time=1000
time_dy2() # to compile
print(timeit.Timer(time_dy2).timeit(number=n_time)/n_time) 

y0 = np.array([1.0])
t_span=np.array([0.0,1.0])

def time_solve_ivp():
    solve_ivp(dy2, t_span, y0, args=(*rates,))

time_solve_ivp() # to compile
print(timeit.Timer(time_solve_ivp).timeit(number=n_time)/n_time)
```

### Passing parameters (n) + solve_ivp

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import timeit

b_f = 1.0

@nb.njit
def  rate_new(t,n):
    return b_f*n*t

@nb.njit
def dy2_new(t,y,argv):
    n1, n2, n3 = argv
    r1 = rate_new(t,n1)
    r2 = rate_new(t,n2)
    r3 = rate_new(t,n3)
    return y

argv = np.array([0,1,2],np.float64)
@nb.njit
def time_dy2():
    dy2_new(1.0,1.0,argv)

n_time=1000
time_dy2() # to compile
print(timeit.Timer(time_dy2).timeit(number=n_time)/n_time) 

y0 = np.array([1.0])
t_span=np.array([0.0,1.0])
t_eval=np.array([0.0,1.0])

def time_solve_ivp():
    sol = solve_ivp(dy2_new, t_span, y0, args=(argv,), t_eval = t_eval)

time_solve_ivp() # to compile
print(timeit.Timer(time_solve_ivp).timeit(number=n_time)/n_time)
```

### Passing parameters (n) + NumbaLSODA

[NumbaLSODA](https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/NumbaLSODA) is an alternative to solve_ivp, which has no overhead, and is much faster.

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from NumbaLSODA import lsoda, lsoda_sig
import timeit

b_f = 1.0

@nb.njit
def  rate_new(t,n):
    return b_f*n*t

@nb.njit
def dy2_new(t,y,argv):
    n1, n2, n3 = argv
    r1 = rate_new(t,n1)
    r2 = rate_new(t,n2)
    r3 = rate_new(t,n3)
    return y

@nb.cfunc(lsoda_sig)
def dy2_new_new(t,y_,dy,argv_):
    argv = nb.carray(argv_,(3,))
    y = nb.carray(y_,(1,))
    dy_ = dy2_new(t,y,argv)
    dy[0] = dy_[0]
    
funcptr = dy2_new_new.address
    
argv = np.array([0,1,2],np.float64)
y0 = np.array([1.0])
t_span=np.array([0.0,1.0])
t_eval=np.array([0.0,1.0])

@nb.njit
def time_NumbaLSODA():
    usol, success = lsoda(funcptr, y0, t_eval, data = argv)
    
time_NumbaLSODA() # to compile
n_time=1000
print(timeit.Timer(time_NumbaLSODA).timeit(number=n_time)/n_time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Unfortunately I cannot seem to install NumbaLSODA (possibly because I am on Windows), but using your recommendation my project is now 10x faster!